# Batch file or script to move files up X levels

Tags: windows, batch-file, parent, move

We currently use a machine that generates a complicated folder structure when outputting it's data and would like to simplify the folder hierarchy of the generated data afterwards.

In our current setting, the directories look like this:

C:\Dir01\Dir02\Dir03\Dir4\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02A\Dir03\Dir4\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02B\Dir03\Dir4\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02C\Dir03\Dir4\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02D\Dir03\Dir4\*.* 
etc.

The Dir01 folder is where all of our samples data are copied

The Dir02 folder(s) are created for each unique sample and will each have a unique name.

The Dir03 only contains the Dir04 folder

Dir03 and Dir04 typically have the same name every time (within a unique named Dir02)

Dir04 is where all the actual data lives and will all have a series of filenames within for every sample...i.e. file.001 file.002 file.003

The Dir04 data would ideally be moved into the Dir02 folder for each sample and then the Dir03 and Dir04 folder should be deleted after moving.

I would like to further separate out specific files within Dir02 after moving and create a new folder (Dir02A) under Dir01 to relocate those files.

In the end I would like to end up with a directory structure like this:

C:\Dir01\Dir02\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02A\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02B\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02C\*.* 
C:\Dir01\Dir02D\*.* 
etc.

Once this is complete I have a batch file that uses robocopy to duplicate the entire directory structure and separate out the non *.dcm files into a new folder, but this still leaves my complicated directory structure.

`robocopy.exe "%SourcePath%" "%DestPath%" /s /xf *.dcm`

That is my primary goal...rid myself of unnecessary directory navigation.

===============
Recap: 
1) Data is generated beneath Dir01 to unique folders (Dir02, Dir02A, Dir02B...) 
2) Run a batch file or script to perform post processing on data under Dir01 
3) Move data from under each Dir04 subfolder to their parent Dir02, Dir02A, Dir02B, etc. folders 
4) Clean up (now empty) Dir03 and Dir04 folders under each Dir02, Dir02A, Dir02B, etc. folder 
5) Run my Robocopy batch file to move all non *.dcm files to a new location

Comment: What do you want to do about the duplicate names in the Dir4 folders? (If they just get copied to Dir2 they will clash, right?). You say "Batch file or script" - would a PowerShell script be usable on that machine?

Comment: I need to move the files in Dir04 to Dir02 and leave the filenames intact.  These files are a series of files generated during our data acquisition, and need to be maintained in the series.

I was just advising that each samples folder (Dir02) would contain duplicate folder and file names within it when compared to the other unique sample folders at the Dir02 level.  

When we are finished generating data in a typical run we can have anywhere from one, to several hundred unique datasets at the Dir02 level.

Comment: The robocopy command I pasted was actually for the moving specific files within that series to another location (excluding *.dcm files) after the initial move of all the data.

Comment: When we are finished generating data in a typical run we can have anywhere from one, to several hundred unique datasets at the Dir02 level.

Comment: I'm sorry, it still isn't clear to me. Can you edit your question with an example, please? I think there is a single Dir01 `c:\out\ `? Inside that, many second level Dir02 folders,  `c:\out\samA `, `c:\out\samB`? `Dir03` is less clear - is it `c:\out\samA\samA\ ` again? Is there anything else in a `Dir02` except this single `Dir03` with the same name? `Dir04` folders - one or many in a Dir03? Dir04 names are duplicated with what, where? Is the whole thing just `c:\out\samA\samA\files\*` to `c:\out\samA\*` for all sam{A}, am I overthinking it because you said it was a complicated structure?

Comment: Correct...Dir01 is a single directory <br>
Dir02 will be created for each scanned sample, possibly a hundred or more of these <br>
Dir03 and Dir04 will be below each unique Dir02 <br>
Dir04 files need to be moved to their parent Dir02(A) folder for each Dir02 sample generated <br>
After moving from Dir04 to Dir02 the empty Dir03 and Dir04 folders should be deleted <br>
From here I can run my Robocopy batch file to copy the new cleaned up directory structure and move specific files to a new location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
cd /d c:\dir01\dir02
forfiles /s /m "*.dcm" /c "cmd.exe /c move @path @path\..\.."
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I will have many unique instances of Dir02.  I am currently using a combination of the search feature with drag and drop to accomplish this task.  Yuck!

Answer (score 0):

This as a batch file should do the first part:

1. Run through every sample folder

   1. for each one, e.g. `c:\out\Dir02F` move `c:\out\Dir02F\dir03\dir04\*` into `c:\out\Dir02F\*`
   2. Remove the Dir03 and Dir04 subfolders

Edit it to cover the right folders, of course, and maybe add a bit at the end to call your Robocopy script for each folder. Tested briefly, but try it on a copy first.

```
for /D %%s in (c:\out\*) do (
    move "%%s\Dir03\Dir04\*" "%%s\"
    rmdir "%%s\Dir03\Dir04"
    rmdir "%%s\Dir03"
)
```

Edit for comment: It will handle every Dir02 folder within Dir01. I think it could be re-written even as:

```
for /D %%s in (d:\t\*) do (
    for /D %%y in (%%s\*) do (
        for /D %%z in (%%y\*) do (
            move "%%z\*" "%%s\"
        )
        rmdir /Q /S %%y
    )
)
```

At least in my quick test that works without caring what Dir03 and Dir04 are called.

Comment: Will this recursively work through all folders in Dir01 ("C:\out\"), or do I need to manually run this for each Dir02?
Is it possible to do this without hard coding paths for Dir03\Dir04?  I want it to be useful in the event those folder names change which is a semi-common occurrence.

Comment: Looking at the "For" command with the wildcards further now....thanks for your code assistance.  I think this might just do what I need, or at the very least give me a great start.  Awesome!

Comment: @RokGoblin : I've updated my answer to address those now. (Thought I commented earlier, in case this double-posts)